# How to migrate a db2 database

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I have a db2 database on a device which does not have internect connectivity and would like to move this database to another place. I have taken a backup from my database, can I use the 'restore' command to create a clone of this database?

Comment: Not enough information. You can use 'restore database' as long as the CPU architecture of the 'another place' matches the source database CPU, and the Db2-version on new place is the same or higher than at the source.  You may need to use a redirected restore and remap tablespaces if the storage layout differs between the source and target hostnames.

Comment: I'm using 'DB2 express' version as the source database and would like to migrate to DB2 on Cloud. Here is the command I'm using but it fails, (DB1 is the name of my source db and bludb is the name of the destination db)
RESTORE DATABASE DB1 FROM "C:\Users\\Desktop\Backup" TAKEN AT 20180409102735 INTO BLUDB NEWLOGPATH "C:\Users\Desktop\New folder" WITHOUT PROMPTING

Comment: "It fails" is not a valid error description. Once again, give *facts*, version-numbers of source-Db2-express,  exact error messages. You cannot use Windows-path-names for Db2-on-cloud (as in your NEWLOGPATH and FROM clause), because most likely the operating-system is Linux-x64. You may need to scp (binary copy) the offline Db2-backup image to cloud filesystem first and restore from there. Also most likely you will need a redirected restore as the filesystem layouts will differ between source and target.

Comment: @mao I'm new to db2, could you help me figuring this out, my questions 1) should I scp the db2-backup to a blob storage? 2) once the backup is on the blob storage, may I know the syntax to restore in db2 on cloud? The source database version is 'Express-C 11.1'

Comment: If you are using an IBM cloud offering, then you need to study https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/CloudIntegration/index-gentopic2.html#genTopProcId3 for moving data. You may need additional education. Stackoverflow may not be the correct place for formal education and training.

Answer (score 1):

To move a Db2 database from on-premise to Db2 Warehouse on Cloud, one option is to use IBM Lift CLI.  https://www.lift-cli.cloud.ibm.com/

You will need to have internet connectivity from the place your data resides on-premise - either a Db2 database, or failing that CSV files.

If all you have is a Db2 backup image, you would need to restore that into a local database, or use the (chargeable) utility High Performance Unload to extract table data as CSV files from the backup image.  IBM Lift CLI does not support Db2 backup images as a source for migration to the cloud.

Note that if you use CSV files, you will need to extract the DDL from the source database and create the empty tables on the target.